# Visual Studio 2015 - Missing Publish to Docker option

Tags: docker, visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core-1.0

I am using Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise. I have installed Visual Studio 2015 Tools for Docker - Preview. Now I created a ASP.Net web application project -  ASP.Net core app on .Net core. It builds fine but when I click Publish - I don't see the option to deploy it on Decker. Pls help.

Answer (score 0):

They removed the publishing ui. recently in Version 0.14.0 Updates.  But they are planning to bring it back in the future.  A few people were talking about it and You can see the discussion in the Q n A section.

the Q n A can be found here
https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0f5b2caa-ea00-41c8-b8a2-058c7da0b3e4/view/Discussions/2

at the end with the title

> Docker Publish ASP.Net 5 Web App / .Net Core 1.0 RC2 option missing 2
>   Posts | Last post June 02, 2016

look for the reply from Steve Lasker (I believe he is the program manager at Microsoft)

Answer (score 0):

In the meanwhile, try to put your Visual Studio Solution to `Release`, and build it.

This will generate a new docker image you can use:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/articles/core/docker/visual-studio-tools-for-docker

Look at: 'Publishing Docker images' at bottom.

Regards.